# How to build example with shared object in GnuTLS

Tags: c, compilation, makefile

I'm trying to compile example from GnuTLS. I can compile GnuTLS with no problem.

I usually use this command when I have default GnuTLS package installed. I compile the example with this commend.

```
gcc -o server ex-serv-srp.c  -lgnutls
```

I build GnuTLS from source. I can compile the example with the same command but when I try to run the example I get this error:

```
./server: error while loading shared libraries: libgnutls.so.28: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The location of `libgnutls.so.28` is in `/usr/local/lib`  directory. How I can link the example during compilation time so that they will know where to find libgnutls.so.28

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable like this `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: yes it works! but I cannot export D_LIBRARY_PATH every time when I need to run the server. Is there another way to solve the problem?

Comment: Well, you *could* make a shell script that sets the variable before running the server. You could also link the program like this: `-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib`

Answer (score 2):

For a permanent solution add `/usr/local/lib` to `/etc/ld.so.conf` and rerun `ldconfig`, otherwise do as zvbra proposes.